# FoldLeft in Terms of FoldRight

Tags: haskell, reinventing-the-wheel

I [believe that I] wrote `foldl` in terms of `foldr`:

```
myFoldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
myFoldl f base xs = foldr (flip f) base (reverse xs)
```

Is this an idiomatic implementation?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I believe it's equivalent to the [third duality theorem](http://www.cantab.net/users/antoni.diller/haskell/units/unit06.html) which states that for any finite list `xs`,

```
foldr op u xs = foldl (flip op) u (reverse xs)
```

Without appealing to the theorem, we can still prove your definition correct for any finite list `xs`. We'll need  definitions of `foldl` and `foldr`:

**Definition**

```
(1) foldr _ u [] = u
(2) foldr op u (x:xs) = op x (foldr op u xs)
```

**Definition**

```
(3) foldl _ u [] = u
(4) foldl op u (x:xs) = foldl op (op u x) xs
```

And the following:

**Lemma** For finite lists `xs`, `ys`, `foldr op u (ys ++ xs) = foldr op (foldr op u xs) ys`.

**Case `[]`**

```
RHS = foldr op (foldr op u xs) []
    = foldr op u xs -- by (1)
    = foldr op u ([] ++ xs)
    = LHS
```

**Case `y:ys`**

```
RHS = foldr op (foldr op u xs) (y:ys)
    = op y (foldr op (foldr op u xs) ys) -- by (2)
    = op y (foldr op u (ys ++ xs)) -- by induction hypothesis
    = foldr op u (y:ys ++ xs) -- by (2)
    = LHS
```

∎

**Claim** For any finite list `xs`, `foldr (flip op) u (reverse xs) = foldl op u xs`.

**Case `[]`**

```
LHS = foldr (flip op) u (reverse [])
    = foldr (flip op) u []
    = [] -- by (1)
    = foldl op u [] -- by (3)
    = RHS
```

**Case `x:xs`**

```
LHS = foldr (flip op) u (reverse (x:xs))
    = foldr (flip op) u ((reverse xs) ++ [x])
    = foldr (flip op) (foldr (flip op) u [x]) (reverse xs) -- by the lemma
    = foldr (flip op) ((flip op) x (foldr (flip op) u [])) (reverse xs) -- by (2)
    = foldr (flip op) ((flip op) x u) (reverse xs) -- by (1)
    = foldl op ((flip op) x u) xs -- by induction hypothesis
    = foldl op (op u x) xs -- by definition of flip
    = foldl op u (x:xs) -- by (4)
    = RHS
```

∎